Run precompiled-qnn-onnx llama2 llm on Qualcomm linux
My need is to use python and load/use LLAMA as LLM. I'm right now targeting llama2-7b.
I'd like to ask which is the preferred way of executing such model on qcs 6490 using a python framework like.
I see that in AI HUB export job, it is supported qnn and precompiled-qnn-onnx, so I was pointing my attention to onnx framework using python.
Is there any example/experience for this?
Or, is there any other recommended way of executing llama2 with python on such hardware, using NPU?
(target device: RB3 Gen 2 - 6490)
Thanks!
